# Allow ssh/sftp file up-/download, but disallow changing existing files

Tags: ssh, permissions, sftp, linuxmint

I have a linux mint machine which provides a kind of file dump which gets provided via a nginx.

My problem is, that a single user (upload_usr) should be able to place new files/directorys inside one specific folder, but he shouldn't be allowed to replace or change any existing file.

This should work like this:

- put a.txt -> fine
- put a.txt -> disallow
- cat a.txt -> fine
- put b.txt -> fine
- rm a.txt -> disallow

Important is, that an other user which isn't root needs to be able to r/w in this dir.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming openssh with sftp-server.)

If you allow SSH then this is nearly impossible. However, if you only allow SFTP:

> should be able to place new files/directorys inside one specific
>   folder

Use `ChrootDirectory`

For the other requirements `-P blacklisted_requests` and `-u umask` should be sufficient. (You can see the request types by running `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests`.)

> put a.txt -> fine

allow `write` (allowed by default)

> put a.txt -> disallow

Run the sftp-server with `-u 0222` and disallow and `setstat` `fsetstat`.

> cat a.txt -> fine

allow `read` (allowed by default)

> put b.txt -> fine

allow `write` (allowed by default)

> rm a.txt -> disallow

disallow `remove` (and `rmdir`?)

TLDR Limit users with `ChrootDirectory` and run `sftp-server` with `-u 0222 -P remove,rmdir,setstat,fsetstat`

Comment: Maybe he can mix your solution with *Match Group* and *ForceCommand*, to force users in group to use SFTP, while keeping ssh enabled.

Comment: Yes, something like `ForceCommand internal-sftp` would disable interactive SSH sessions.